# Docker registry catalog API restricted at the user level

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm setting up a docker registry using the container provided in the official documentation.

I setup the token authentication for the registry and I would like to consume the catalog API, e.g. for
listing repositories, but I would like to restrict it at the user level.

Therefore, an authenticated user, at the point of calling myregistry.com/v2/_catalog it will get as part
of the response body just the repositories where he has access.

Is there any middleware mechanism that can be easily implemented within the current docker registry
version?

If not, what is the recommended approach you would suggest in order to fulfil this use case.